# Saving files in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

I've been running through docs and everything for the past couple of hours but with no success...
I want to download a file from *some server* and to **save it** on my phone (the directory where the app stores files that are only visible to my app and are deleted when the app is uninstalled). I would like to **store** a file and **write** to it (I've done the download part). With the following code, when I run it, it works and display the text from the "file" but when I search for the file using some file explorer apps, the file that I've "created" is nowhere near to be found.

Cheers!

EDIT Notes:
Okay so I've now even tried to create a file on my phone from the computer using a usb connection so I know for a fact the the file exists...
The path of the file where I created it from the pc is:

> This PC\Galaxy S7 edge\Phone\Android\data\com.phonegap.musicapp2\text.txt

The response code that I get from JSON.stringify(dirEntry) is the following

```
{"isFile":false,"isDirectory":true,"name":"com.phonegap.musicapp2","fillPath":"/data/user/0/com.phonegap.musicapp2/", "filesystem":"","nativeURL":"file:///data/user/0/com.phonegap.musiapp2/"}
```

So when I run the code from bellow, it gives me

> Error from getFile: {"code":1}

I've looked through the docs and it says that code 1 mean: NOT_FOUND_ERR (http://prntscr.com/n071kx)

"Code from bellow"

```
function readFile(fileEntry) {

    fileEntry.file(function (file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function() {
            DebugConsole.log("Successful file read: " + this.result);
            //  displayFileData(fileEntry.fullPath + ": " + this.result);
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);

    }, onErrorReadFile);
}

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory, function(dirEntry) {

    DebugConsole.log(JSON.stringify(dirEntry));

    dirEntry.getFile('text.txt', {create: false, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {

        //writeFile(fileEntry, null, isAppend);
        readFile(fileEntry);

    }, function(e) {

        DebugConsole.log('Error from getFile: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
    });
});
```

**Sidenote:**
App never asks for permission to access my internal storage.
I went into Apps/myapp/permissions and it showed that the app doesn't have permission to access the storage. I turned it on but still no luck.
I think I need to somehow request storage access from the app but I can't seem to find a way how?

Comment: you should try to run a media scanner

Comment: @KeySee Care to explain please? (EDIT: Nvm, scanned it and still no files)

Comment: try to save it to the root of the microsd or of the emulated space, you could check even if there is an Music folder

Comment: I've edited the question with more info

Comment: try with cordova-plugin-file-transfer instead, it allows you to download and store in a single call ;) https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution with the following

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "Android/data/app.name/files/", success, fail);
```

Comment: I would raccomand you to use cordova.file.dataDirectory which is the same but more reliable

Comment: @KeySee Nah, doesn't work... it doesn't create a file anywhere even though it says it successfully created

Comment: Strange, make sure to test it against other android's too